# What is the WORKSHEETS_APP_USER in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

While looking at our `snowflake.account_usage.login_history` in order to identify users with outdated client drivers (using `reported_client_type` + `reported_client_version`), I came across this `user_name` that I did not recognize: `WORKSHEETS_APP_USER`.

It's not one of our users, so I'm wondering where it's coming from.

- The client driver it's using is `OTHER 1.1.5`.
- It's using `OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN` to authenticate (which is not an authentication method we use for Snowflake).
- And it's using a ***ton*** of different IPs in the `10.4.*` range.
- It has a lot more logins during the week than during the weekend -- so probably a human(s).

I'm thinking it's probably related to the worksheets UI (either in Snowsight or in the old console).

If so, would there be any way to know who was the *original* user(s) behind this activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first time Snowsight is accessed in an account, Snowflake creates an internal WORKSHEETS_APP_USER user to support the web interface. This user is used to cache query results in an internal stage in your account. For more information, see Getting Started With Snowsight.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/users.html#usage-notes